# undefined reference to, why

Tags: c++, templates

g++: undefined reference to `A::sc', why? But statement a=sc is OK.
because of the template?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
inline const T &min(const T &left, const T &right)
{
     return (left < right ? left : right);
}

class A 
{
public:
   static const size_t sc = 0;
   A() 
    {   
      size_t tmp = 0;
      size_t a = sc; 
      size_t b = min(sc, tmp);
    }   
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's because `sc` is passed by reference to `min`. Once you take a reference to it, it can't be a compile-time constant anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have

```
static const size_t sc = 0;
```

as a class member, it is still a declaration. If you use only its value in your program, you don't need to define it. However, if you use it by reference, you have to define it using:

```
const size_t A::sc;
```

The line

```
  size_t a = sc;
```

uses `sc` by value but the line

```
  size_t b = min(sc, tmp);
```

uses `sc` by reference. For that reason, `sc` needs to be defined.

Comment: Extra fun fact: `min(+sc, tmp)` wouldn't trigger the error ;)

Comment: @Quentin, that deserves its own answer, if you ask me.

Comment: Meh. I'm not that clear on the technical stuff around ODR-uses, and actually using that trick would be too arcane IMO.